# Car interior rattles on idle

Tags: engine, maintenance, troubleshooting

My carb Citroën BX interior rattles on idle.
This mostly happens before the engine warms up, as soon as I apply the smallest amount of throttle this disappears, which leads me to apply throttle when stopped at lights or keep my choke activated  for nllonger than usual.

Here's a video reference https://youtu.be/ry84LsLrOuA
The sound is louder on the recording

Answer (score 1):

It may indicate that either you need to wait a while to put the choke in or that you need the idle screw adjusted on your carburetor.

Comment: How would I know wich is the solution? I'm guessing it's not the choke since my car doesn't struggle to start after I stop, but I'm just guessing.

What's the recomended way to use a choke?

Comment: Use the choke until the car warms up properly.  You can reduce the amount of choke gradually until it's fully off and keep the car running smooth.

Comment: I'll take that in to account. Shame I can just guess since my car doesn't have a temp gauge.